# Card-based vs. card-game and when to use them

Tags: discussion, tags

So it looks like things have progressed from ["Let's use genre tags if there's room"](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/when-should-we-use-genre-tags) to ["Let's use them only for questions about genre"](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1857/underused-genre-tags), at least as far as I could determine.

Anyway, I was looking at an [ITG question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25905/help-in-identifying-a-multiplayer-strategy-card-game) that was tagged with a number of things, two of which were [card-based](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-based) and [card-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-game). That didn't seem right to me, so I was thinking maybe the tags should be changed, except I'm not sure which to use.

There are few questions tagged with either genre, which makes sense given the latest stance on genre tagging and the relative lack of questions on either type of game ... but the few questions that are tagged don't seem to be consistent.

[Card-game questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-game) include the ITG one and questions on Skip98 (a freeware version of Skip-bo) and solitaire, so I get both of those: computer versions of actual card games. But the other question is about Yu-Gi-Oh!.

[Card-based questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-based) questions are even rarer, and include only the ITG and two questions about Duels of the Planeswalkers. So ...

- None of these questions are actually about the genre. Should they even be tagged in the first place? (Possible exception: ITG questions, although if the only reason we tag a question is because it's ITG, then there isn't much point in tagging it, is there?)
- If they should be tagged, shouldn't Yu-Gi-Oh! and any Magic game be in the same category?
- If they shouldn't be tagged, is that an answer to Mana's question about genre tags, that it's OK to remove them, or is this a case-by-case thing?

Comment: I don't like using genre tags when the question is about a specific game and already tagged as such.  The genre tag is then redundant.