# What is the purpose of genre tags like 'roguelikes' if not to clarify the genre of a question?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should we use genre tags?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/when-should-we-use-genre-tags)
>   [How should I tag on gaming SE? (Are genre tags used?)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/how-should-i-tag-on-gaming-se-are-genre-tags-used)

I incorrectly answered [a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60890/whats-a-good-strategy-for-defeating-the-cyberdemon) about doomrl. The original author had tagged it with 'roguelikes', but an editor removed that tag. Had that tag existed, it would have provided the context needed to avoid providing a bad answer.

I submitted a retag on it that appears to have been shot down in peer review; is there a reason that roguelikes is a bad tag for this question? Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the tag?

Comment: The long and short of it is we only use them for questions *about the genre*, as given our tag limit (5) and the fact that many games are cross-genre nowadays, it's not feasible for us to support genre tags for classifying games in questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I declined that tag edit.  The [doomrl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doomrl) tag is distinct enough to tell you it is the roguelike.

The purpose of the genre tags can be found [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/how-should-i-tag-on-gaming-se-are-genre-tags-used/3321#3321).