# Statistical data on tag usage

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we have any data on which tags are used by people? By used I mean e.g. having it as a favorite tag or browsing the tag specifically.

My suspicion is that all tags except for the game-name tag and maybe the genre tag are not used at all. I would be interested if we had any hard data on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have any, to my knowledge. We don't even have a slot in the public data-dump, yet. Tag preferences will also not be published, because that is private data. But I think your guess is going to be pretty accurate.

That said, as I tried to get at [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1356/what-should-be-done-about-strategy-and-similar-tags-what-conventions-should-we), I think there's an important point that down the road, the non-name/genre/platform tags will be a lot more useful once we have more content. Parsing through game-name might be sufficient now. But once we get more games, and those games get more questions, it becomes more useful to be able to sift, say, questions about [weapons] in Sora from questions about [bosses]. Or something. We don't actually have a [bosses] tag.

In terms of what to observe and what not to: tag preferences probably only help for the game name, genre, and/or platform. Past that, the main use of the other tags will be more for sifting within a specific game to find answers to a question, rather than questions to give answers. Which is entirely a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Now that we are part of the Data Explorer, there is data available on tags. Unfortunately, we don't have access to the specific items you want to know, views or favorites at the tag level.

We do, however, have access to views and favorites at the question level, so you can look at something like [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/q/111132/totals-by-tag-for-open-questions) to get an idea of how tag usage has changed during the first year of being a live site. While games, genres, and platforms do have the most questions, tags like [spoiler](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler), [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achievements), and [strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) are fairly popular at the question level too.